# IlleagalMonitorStateException when I am trying to run this program 

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class ThreadTest
{
 public static Integer i = new Integer(0);

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
 {
  ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest();
  Runnable odd = threadTest.new Numbers(1, "thread1");
  Runnable even = threadTest.new Numbers(0, "thread2");
  ((Thread) odd).start();
  ((Thread) even).start();
 }

 class Numbers extends Thread
 {
  int reminder;
  String threadName;

  Numbers(int reminder, String threadName)
  {
   this.reminder = reminder;
   this.threadName = threadName;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
   while (i < 20)
   {
    synchronized (i)
    {
     if (i % 2 == reminder)
     {
      System.out.println(threadName + " : " + i);
      i++;
      i.notify();
     }
     else
     {
      try
      {
       i.wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't synchronize on `i` because it changes during execution of your program.

Since `Integer` in Java is immutable, after executing `i++` `i` will contain a reference to another object, not the object you have `synchronized` on. So, you can't call `wait()`/`notify()` on this new object, because these methods may be only called on the object you are `synchronized` on, otherwise you get `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

You need to synchronize on some other object that doesn't change during execution. For example, you may create a separate object for this purpose:

```
public class ThreadTest { 
    public static Integer i = new Integer(0); 
    public static Object lock = new Object();
    ...
    class Numbers extends Thread { 
        ...
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
             ...
             synchronized (lock) {
                 ...
                 lock.notify();
                 ...
                 lock.wait();
                 ...
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
i++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
i = i + 1;
```

which (due to autoboxing) becomes something like:

```
i = new Integer(i.intValue() + 1);
```

So, when you call `i.notify()` you are synchronized on the *old* `i`, not the new one.

I'd suggest changing `i` into an ordinary `int` variable, and create a separate object to synchronize on:

```
static int i = 0;
static Object iMonitor = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

As documentation states the exception is thrown when

> the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor

It also states that

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor.

And this condition can be obtained by

- By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
- By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.
- For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.

You could try calling the wait method from inside the class that uses `i`. This could be done by extending the class and writing two new methods for `notify` and `wait`..

Answer (score -1):

You cannot put wait() and notify() in the same synchronized block because that will just cause a deadlock. Make sure only the wait and notify functions are wrapped with a synchronized block like this:

```
synchronized (i) {
    i.wait(); // or i.notify();
}
```